# Compilation options of a multi-output model: multiple losses & loss weighting

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

As described in the Keras handbook -*Deep Learning with Pyhton*-, for a multi-output model we need to specify different loss functions for different heads of the network. But because gradient descent requires you to minimize a scalar, you must combine these losses into a single value in order to train the model.

Very imbalanced loss contributions will cause the model representations to be optimized preferentially for the task with the largest individual loss, at the expense of the other tasks. To remedy this, you can assign different levels of importance to the loss values in their contribution to the final loss. This is useful in particular if the losses’ values use different scales.

Can anyone help with the following:

I've got a five-output model with the following outputs:

1. emotion (multiclass, multilabel classification)
2. valence (regression)
3. arousal (regression)
4. dominance (regression)
5. age (multiclass classification)

I am using the following :

```
losses_list = {'EMOTIONS': 'binary_crossentropy',
               'VALENCE': 'mse',
               'AROUSAL': 'mse',
               'DOMINANCE': 'mse',
               'AGE': 'categorical_crossentropy'}


losses_weights = {'EMOTIONS': 1.0,
                  'VALENCE': 0.025,
                  'AROUSAL': 0.025,
                  'DOMINANCE': 0.025,
                  'AGE': 0.45}

metrics ={'EMOTIONS': 'crossentropy',
          'VALENCE': 'mse',
          'AROUSAL': 'mse',
          'DOMINANCE': 'mse',
          'AGE': 'categorical_accuracy'}
```

**Are those the right loss functions? Are those the right weights and are those metrics properly set?**

Answer (score 1):

1. Are those the right loss functions? Yes, well played.
2. Are those the right weights? You decide how the training should be affected by the various losses, mostly depends on your data, for example if valence is noisy, you might want to reduce its weight which you did.
3. Are those metrics properly set? The first should be `binary_accuracy`, for regression often `mae` or mean absolute error is used, the last one is correct for multi-class classification.

Comment: Thanks for that. As stated in the book 
''For instance, the mean squared error (MSE) loss
used for the age-regression task typically takes a value around 3–5, whereas the crossentropy
loss used for the gender-classification task can be as low as 0.1. In such a situation,
to balance the contribution of the different losses, you can assign a weight of 10
to the crossentropy loss and a weight of 0.25 to the MSE loss.'' 
So, based on that my question is what are the typical values for the loss functions used in my example?